# Achievements in Bioshock--New Game Plus

Tags: achievements, ps3, bioshock

Alright so here's a synopsis of my situation: I'm trying to get all the achievements in Bioshock 1. I downloaded the add-ons and stuff, and noticed the new game plus feature. I thought this would help in getting achievements, but have been hearing rumors that they don't carry over into your new game. Is that correct?

Also, do weapon upgrades and research carry over and still contribute to the achievements?

Comment: Add-ons?  You mean mods?  If it's not an official add-on, chances are pretty good it prevents gaining achievements.

Comment: Are you talking about the PS3 version? I'm not aware of any Add-ons or DLCs for Bioshock 1 on Xbox 360, plus there is no Achievements for the Steam version of Bioshock (and I don't think you can play Bioshock 1 without Steam either). Additionally, I wasn't aware that Bioshock 1 featured a "*New Game Plus*".

Comment: NG+ was an addition for the PS3 version of Bioshock, which was released as a patch and also included challenge rooms. http://www.ps3news.com/PlayStation3/2k-games-bioshock-ps3-patch-coming-to-fix-texture-issues/

Answer (score 1):

According to [2K staff on their forums](http://forums.2k.com/showthread.php?24135&p=370290#post370290), it is **not possible** to gain trophies/achievements in the *New Game+* mode of *BioShock*.

As for what carries over:

> New Game Plus allows players the ability to start a new game **with the character data (weapons, inventory, research, etc.) carried over** from the end of the game (if they beat the game after the patch was installed) or from a saved game of their choosing (if they beat the game before the patch was installed).
>   […]
>   When using New Game Plus, **you will gain access to all of the tonics, plasmids, and weapons you have acquired previously in the game**. However, you will not be able to access these goodies until you reach Medical, when you will receive all the weapons you had previously uncovered, and three plasmids. The remainder of your plasmids and tonics will be waiting for you at the first Gene Bank you access.